# Fatal error LNK1168: cannot open filename.mexw64 for writing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matlab, cuda, mex

I am writing a c++/CUDA code with **Visual Studio 2015** to generate a **mex** file to integrate with **MATLAB**.

When I run the mex file through the MATLAB console and then try to compile it again on VS I get this error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open filename.mexw64 for writing

- Closing the MATLAB and opening the programme again solves the problem.

Does anyone know any solution which not involves closing the MATLAB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MEX-files are DLLs (on Windows, shared objects on other systems). When first run, MATLAB links to them, but doesn't unlink unless explicitly told to (or quitting MATLAB of course).

Typing

```
clear mex
```

in MATLAB will unlink all MEX-files. See [the relevant documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html#btdyzbv-1-ItemType).

But note that your MEX-file can call [`mxLock`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexlock.html), which will cause it to be locked in memory and then it will not be cleared by `clear mex`. If you use this function in your MEX-file, you need to include a facility to have your MEX-file call `mxUnlock`. I usually add a syntax such as `mymexfile --unlock`: the MEX-file checks to see if it is called with one argument, and that argument is a string, and the string matches "--unlock", then it calls `mxUnlock`.

Comment: If I run the .mex file and then enter *clear mex*, MATLAB stop working.

A working around for this was to execute **reset(gpuDevice(1))** and then after it, the command *clear mex* works fine all the times.

Comment: @RodrigoVimieiro: You likely need to use [`mexAtExit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexatexit.html) to specify a cleanup function in your MEX-file. This function needs to release any resources that you allocate in the MEX-file, and would be the place to put the GPU cleanup routines.

Comment: should I place the `cudaFree` and `cudaDeviceReset` functions on the `mexAtExit`? Is it a good practice to call `cudaDeviceReset` at the end of my code?

Comment: @Rodrigo: The `mexAtExit` function should free any resources that are allocated only once when the MEX-file is run for the first time. Resources that you allocate every time that the MEX-file is run should be freed every time the MEX-file is run, and therefore should be freed at the end of the `mexFunction`, not in `mexAtExit`. There's an example MEX-file that uses `mexAtExit`, you'll see it if you type: `edit([matlabroot '/extern/examples/mex/mexatexit.c']);` at the MATLAB command prompt. I don't know enough about CUDA to recommend how and when to call `cudaFree` or `cudaDeviceReset`.